# SNMP4j - Cannot send RESPONSE PDU on some OID

Tags: response, snmp, snmp4j

I'm trying to respond to SNMP GET requests from [SnmpB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpb/) with SNMP4j 2.3.1 (running on Windows).

In "Discover" mode, SnmpB queries by broadcasting 255.255.255.255 (checked with Wireshark) and I receive a GET request with standard OID (sysDescr, sysUpTime, sysContact, sysName and sysLocation). It finds my instance with the information I coded ("My System", "Myself", ...) (note that it also works when I enter the IP address under the "IP networks" textboxes, though I don't see any traffic on Wireshark but I receive the GET request):

[image: SnmpB discovery]

I did write a very simple MIB file that I imported into SnmpB. It defines a single `Integer32` data that I want to retrieve using an SNMP GET request from SnmpB.

However, using the **same code** than for the standard sys* OID, SnmpB doesn't seem to receive that data ("Timeout" in red on the top-right):

[image: SnmpB timeout]

I did try Wireshark to check network activity and I don't see anything, so I guess it takes place on localhost (which is [not accessible with Wireshark on Windows](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback))? But the traces below show it does not (`peerAddress=192.168.56.1`)...

Here is the MIB file (code follows):

```
MY-TEST-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
    enterprises, MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, Integer32
        FROM SNMPv2-SMI;

myTest MODULE-IDENTITY
    LAST-UPDATED "201412301216Z"
    ORGANIZATION "My org"
    CONTACT-INFO "Matthieu Labas"
    DESCRIPTION "MIB Test"
    REVISION "201412301216Z"
    DESCRIPTION "Generated"
    ::= { enterprises 12121 }

myData OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX Integer32
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION "My data for test"
    ::= { myTest 1 }

END
```

... and the code:

```
public class RespondGET implements CommandResponder {

    public static final OID sysDescr = new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");
    public static final OID sysUpTime = new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0");
    public static final OID sysContact = new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0");
    public static final OID sysName = new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0");
    public static final OID sysLocation = new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0");

    public static final OID myData = new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.12121.1.0");

    private Snmp snmp;

    public RespondGET() throws IOException {
        MessageDispatcher dispatcher = new MessageDispatcherImpl();
        dispatcher.addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv2c()); // v2c only
        snmp = new Snmp(dispatcher, new DefaultUdpTransportMapping(new UdpAddress("192.168.56.1/161"), true));
        snmp.addCommandResponder(this);
        snmp.listen();
    }

    @Override
    public void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Received PDU "+event);
        PDU pdu = event.getPDU();
        switch (pdu.getType()) {
            case PDU.GET:
                List<VariableBinding> responses = new ArrayList<VariableBinding>(pdu.size());
                for (VariableBinding v : pdu.getVariableBindings()) {
                    OID oid = v.getOid();
                    // Answer the usual SNMP requests
                    if (sysDescr.equals(oid)) {
                        responses.add(new VariableBinding(oid, new OctetString("My System description")));
                    } else if (sysUpTime.equals(oid)) {
                        responses.add(new VariableBinding(oid, new TimeTicks(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime())));
                    } else if (sysContact.equals(oid)) {
                        responses.add(new VariableBinding(oid, new OctetString("Myself")));
                    } else if (sysName.equals(oid)) {
                        responses.add(new VariableBinding(oid, new OctetString("My System")));
                    } else if (sysLocation.equals(oid)) {
                        responses.add(new VariableBinding(oid, new OctetString("In here")));
                    } else if (myData.equals(oid)) { // MyData handled here
                        responses.add(new VariableBinding(oid, new Integer32(18)));
                    }
                }

                try {
                    CommunityTarget comm = new CommunityTarget(event.getPeerAddress(), new OctetString(event.getSecurityName()));
                    comm.setSecurityLevel(event.getSecurityLevel());
                    comm.setSecurityModel(event.getSecurityModel());
                    PDU resp = new PDU(PDU.RESPONSE, responses);
                    System.out.println(String.format("Sending response PDU to %s/%s: %s", event.getPeerAddress(), new String(event.getSecurityName()), resp));
                    snmp.send(resp, comm);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(String.format("Unable to send response PDU! (%s)", e.getMessage()));
                }
                event.setProcessed(true);
                break;

            default:
                System.err.println(String.format("Unhandled PDU type %s.", PDU.getTypeString(pdu.getType())));
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RespondGET rg = new RespondGET();
        System.out.println("Listening...");
        int n = 300; // 5 min
        while (true) {
            try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            if (--n <= 0) break;
        }
        System.out.println("Stopping...");
        rg.snmp.close();
    }

}
```

It produces the following output when I click "discover" under SnmpB and right-click on `myData` in the MIB Tree and "Get" (slightly reformatted for readability):

```
Listening...
Received PDU CommandResponderEvent[securityModel=2, securityLevel=1, maxSizeResponsePDU=65535,
    pduHandle=PduHandle[16736], stateReference=StateReference[msgID=0,pduHandle=PduHandle[16736],
    securityEngineID=null,securityModel=null,securityName=public,securityLevel=1,
    contextEngineID=null,contextName=null,retryMsgIDs=null], pdu=GET[requestID=16736, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0,
    VBS[1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = Null; 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Null; 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 = Null; 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = Null; 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 = Null]],
    messageProcessingModel=1, securityName=public, processed=false, peerAddress=192.168.56.1/49561, transportMapping=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@120d62b, tmStateReference=null]

Sending response PDU to 192.168.56.1/49561/public: RESPONSE[requestID=0, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0,
    VBS[1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = My System description; 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = 0:01:03.18; 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 = Myself; 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = My System; 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0 = In here]]

Received PDU CommandResponderEvent[securityModel=2, securityLevel=1, maxSizeResponsePDU=65535,
    pduHandle=PduHandle[1047], stateReference=StateReference[msgID=0,pduHandle=PduHandle[1047],
    securityEngineID=null,securityModel=null,securityName=public,securityLevel=1,
    contextEngineID=null,contextName=null,retryMsgIDs=null], pdu=GET[requestID=1047, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0,
    VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.12121.1.0 = Null]], messageProcessingModel=1, securityName=public, processed=false, peerAddress=192.168.56.1/49560, transportMapping=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@120d62b, tmStateReference=null]

Sending response PDU to 192.168.56.1/49560/public: RESPONSE[requestID=0, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0, VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.12121.1.0 = 18]]

Stopping...
```

What am I missing here? Could that "just" be a network routing issue?

Comment: I think windows is being clever and routing the traffic over your loopback interface, even though you use the external address. So you shouldn't expect to be able to snoop it as long as you run agent and manager on the same host.

Comment: @Jolta it would explain why I don't see anything on Wireshark, but not why SnmpB does not receive my response PDU though. I'm guessing it could be a problem with it, I'll try another one if I can find some time...

Comment: Did you try running them on separate machines? It your response message is invalid, it would explain the behavior, and a good way to see if it's malformed is checking in Wireshark.

Comment: @Jolta not yet, I'm a little bit lazy (and have only my laptop) during the holidays ;) But I think it's worth setting up a VM to check the frames. Though in the end it will run on the same computer.

Comment: @Jolta I just unlazied and installed SnmpB on a VirtualBox. It turned out I forgot to set the proper request ID in my response PDU. If you can say that in an answer I'd be happy to accept it. I'll also add my own answer to show the tests results. And happy new year! :).

Comment: Great, you solved it yourself with only minimal "prodding" from others =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up a VM and checking with Wireshark, it turned out I forgot to set, on the response PDU, the same request ID than the GET PDU.

[image: GET request ID]
[image: Response null request ID]

It was solved by adding `resp.setRequestID(pdu.getRequestID());` when building the response PDU

```
CommunityTarget comm = new CommunityTarget(event.getPeerAddress(), new OctetString(event.getSecurityName()));
comm.setSecurityLevel(event.getSecurityLevel());
comm.setSecurityModel(event.getSecurityModel());
PDU resp = new PDU(PDU.RESPONSE, responses);
resp.setRequestID(pdu.getRequestID()); // Forgot that!
snmp.send(resp, comm);
```

[image: SnmpB received PDU]

Thanks to @Jolta for his patience during New Year holiday and his insisting on using Wireshark for further checking. :)